# How to pass std::string to const unsigned char ** in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

How can I pass std::string to unsigned char **?

Example:

```
/* Func declaration */
void get_string(const unsigned char **str, int *len) {

/* Caller func */
std::string str;
int len = 0;
get_string((const unsigned char **)str.c_str(), &len)      // Can we do this?
```

Comment: ***Can we do this?*** No.

Comment: Do I have to define unsigned char * and then pass reference? Is there any way to do this with std::string?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all this magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation of `get_string` and understand what the semantics are of the argument it is expecting.

I'm going to assume for now that the arguments are both output parameters and it outputs a view onto a string that alraedy exists.

`std::string` manages a string, it can't act just as a view. So you would need to create a new string that is a copy of the one being viewed.  The code could be:

```
unsigned char const *s;
int len;
get_string(&s, &len);
std::string str( (char*)s, len );
```

---

If your compiler is up to date with the latest language standard (C++17) then you can use a view:

```
std::string_view str( (char*)s, len );
```

assuming of course that the view is sufficient for whatever you intend to do with it later.

Comment: Sure thanks, @M.M. I was trying to avoid extra copy. But I think there is no alternative way. Np.

Comment: The semantics of `get_string()` could also potentially expect the caller to "take ownership" of the `char` array being output to `str` and delete it when it's done.  In that case, I'd first wrap the returned pointer into a `unique_ptr<char[]>` (just in case of exceptions in the `string` constructor) and then construct the `string` object similarly.